# Request in Graph Explorer to list root children returns empty

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In a OneDrive account I have 14 files and a folder.
Using Graph Explorer (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/) I get, at the end of json, these values:

```
"folder": {
    "childCount": 15
},
"root": {}
```

but when I try to get the list of files (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children) I get nothing:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX')/drive/root/children",
"value": []}
```

why? How can I get a list of all files and folders?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using the call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root?$expand=children` and see if it works.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity nothing:
`"folder": {
        "childCount": 15
    },
    "root": {},
    "children@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX')/drive/root/children",
    "children": []`

Comment: Please check if you have added permission Files.Read or Files.Read.All or Sites.Read.All.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Please let us know if you still face the issue.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity sorry but I couldn't work on it anymore. Yes I have added all the permissions in Azure Active Directory, both Delegated and Application. And granted for my user. But nothing, it doesn't work.